# Displaying One to Many attributes in a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im new to web development and I'm building a website for a friends business. Im trying to display details relative to a Boar but each boar has multiple selling points (shown in example image). I'm struggling with getting the selling points to the view. I've managed to get the Boar data to display successfully but I want a bulleted list of the selling points for each Boar (as shown in the image).

## Boar.cs

```
public partial class Boar
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Boar()
    {
        SellingPoints = new HashSet<SellingPoint>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Boar_Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Farrowed { get; set; }

    public byte? LitterSize { get; set; }

    public byte? Price { get; set; }

    public bool? GuaranteedSettle { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string StressTest { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string NameNoSpaces { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Sire { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string SireFull { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Dam { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string DamFull { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Breed { get; set; }

    public byte? Order { get; set; }

    public bool? Featured { get; set; }

    public short? FeaturedOrder { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string EarNotch { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string RegNum { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string TestData { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string BredBy { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string OwnedBy { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SellingPoint> SellingPoints { get; set; }
}
```

## SellingPoint.cs

```
[Table("SellingPoint")]
public partial class SellingPoint
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal SellingPoints_Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? Boar_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Boar Boar { get; set; }
}
```

## SellingPoints.cs

```
[Table("SellingPoints")]
public partial class SellingPoint1
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string SellingPoint { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? SellingPoints_Id { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

## Query Used for example

```
SELECT Boars.Boar_Id, Boars.Name, Boars.Price, Boars.Breed, Boars.Sire, Boars.Dam, Boars.NameNoSpaces, SellingPoints.SellingPoint FROM Boars INNER JOIN SellingPoint ON Boars.Boar_Id = SellingPoint.Boar_Id  JOIN SellingPoints ON SellingPoint.SellingPoints_Id = SellingPoints.SellingPoints_Id
```

## Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ShipleySwine.Boar>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    string imgURL;
    int counter = 0;
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<div class="container">

<div class="row row-centered">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        imgURL = "../Boars/" + item.Breed + "/" + item.NameNoSpaces + "/Thumbs/" + item.NameNoSpaces + "1.jpg";

        if (counter == 2)
        {
        @:</div>
        @:<div class="row">

            counter = 0;
        }

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(imgURL)" class="card-img" alt="Photo Didnt Load">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h6 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sire) | @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dam)</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <h4>$ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</h4>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPoints)</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        counter++;
    }
</div>
```

[image: Final View][image: Database Design][image: Multiple SellingPoints]

Comment: Since the `SellingPoint` is a list you have to loop through the collection and print them individually Or you can create a view model that will contain each Boar, a list of SellingPonts and other things.

Comment: SellingPoints table is not needed physically, its a virtual collection as specified in the Boar model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to display the `SellingPoint` in the view

```
@foreach (var _it in item)
{
    <ul>
        <li><p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">@_it.SellingPoint</small></p></li>
    </ul> 
}
```